# MP4 video does not play on mobile

Tags: android, html, firefox, video

https://ymcasports.org/index.cfm/action/ynational_highlights/content_action/ynational_highlights/league/3636/album/4314#15083

The videos on this page play fine on Android but do not play on chrome for android and only audio for firefox for android.

Comment: I'm sorry, but statements are not questions. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was clear by the subject. The video doesnt play on mobile. The question is why?

Answer (score 0):

Your Video has 4:2:2 colorspace but most hardware decoders only support 4:2:0 profile currently (in a few years future, this might change).

Anyway, i see the video was created using ffmpeg already. All you need to do is to add -pix_fmt yuv420p to the ffmpeg command.

[EDIT] for video format related questions, in future, please post a mediainfo report as well: https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline